# How to check that dots in the line?

Tags: ruby, cartesian-coordinates

I'm trying to realize the [Tic-Tac-Toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) game in ruby. I have cartesian coordinates (0 < x <= 3, 0 < y <= 3).

```
x|x|x
- - -
x|x|x
- - -
x|x|x
```

A place in the table above with `x` is where I can place an `x` or `o` sign. How can I check whether a collection of a few signs organize a straight line?

Comment: Define "collection of a few signs".

Comment: Note that any two positions will organize a straight line. And no four positions will organize a straight line. In case of a collection of a single sign, do you take that to be trivially organizing a straight line, or undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the outcome looks like this on paper:

```
x o o
x o x
o x o
```

and you want to know if there is a winner, and if so, who won. That drawing can be represented by the array:

```
toe = [[:x, :o, :o], [:x, :o, :x], [:o, :x, :o]]
```

(I could have used strings `'x'` and `'o'`, but using symbols is more efficient and saves keystrokes. I could have also used `0` and `1` or `true` and `false`, but there are no advantages in doing so.)

Let's define a method the returns `:x` if `x` wins, `:o` if `o` wins or `:no_winner` if there is no winner:

```
def winner?(toe)
  return :x if player_wins?(toe, :x)  
  return :o if player_wins?(toe, :o)  
  :no_winner
end
```

where `player_wins?(toe, p)` is a method that returns `true` or `false`, depending on whether player `p` (`:x` or `:o`) wins. To write that method we could use the following *helper methods* (which you can test individually).

**Are any of the rows winners for player `p`?**

```
def row_win?(toe, p)
  toe.any? { |row| row.uniq == p }
end
```

**Is the main diagonal a winner for player `p`?**

```
def diag_win?(toe, p)
  3.times.all? { |i| toe[i][i] == p }
end
```

**Is the off-diagonal a winner for player `p`?**

```
def off_diag_win?(toe, p)
  3.times.all? { |i| toe[2-i][i] == p }
end
```

With these helpers we can write `player_wins?` as folows:

```
def player_wins?(toe, p)
  row_win?(toe, p)           ||
  row_win?(toe.transpose, p) ||
  diag_win?(toe, p)          ||
  off_diag_win?(toe, p)
end
```

Let's try it:

```
winner?(toe)
  #=> :o
```

Another example:

```
winner? [[:x, :o, :o], [:o, :o, :x], [:x, :x, :o]]
  #=> :no_winner
```